# Error on ProgressDialog Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am using ProgressDialog in my app but on running the app errors occurred.

**Here is the code**

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity{


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

        ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();

    }
}
```

**Updated Code:**

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

```
public static ProgressDialog dialog;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}


 private static abstract class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



     public DictionaryOpenHelper() {
        super(null, null, null, 0);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DictionaryOpenHelper.this, "", 
                "Loading. Please wait...", true);  

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


 }
```

}

> and give error on     ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DictionaryOpenHelper.this, "", 
>                       "Loading. Please wait...", true);  :
>
> The method show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, boolean) in the type ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity.DictionaryOpenHelper, String, String, boolean)

Comment: its not issue with the dialog its with your DB

Comment: sory i uploded the wrong logcat. now i have updated my logcat in the question

Comment: make it a part of UI thread and then load and unload i have posted answer check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-18 06:26:07.273: E/AndroidRuntime(3853):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:524)
```

Load and Unload Progress Dialog  Can be Attempt with the Following Snippet 
make it a part of UIThread 
///load

```
  private ProgressDialog pDialogTh = null;
      private void showLoading() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // if(pDialog==null)
                pDialogTh = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "", "Loading...",
                        true, true);
                pDialogTh.setCancelable(false);
                if (!pDialogTh.isShowing()) {
                    pDialogTh.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

///////Unload

```
private void hideLoading() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (pDialogTh.isShowing()) {
                pDialogTh.cancel();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ok. At this time i have an inner class and i want to use this ProgressDialog in inner class pDialogTh = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "", "Loading...) but i am receiving error on YourActivity.this

Comment: try to run your code in the main activity thread 
 that is 
runOnUiThread()

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(yourActivity.this, "", 
                        "Loading. Please wait...", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mDialog.show();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hi change getApplicationContext() to your activity name

```
  ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using tab and in that you want progress dialog then...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
    mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mDialog.show();

}
}
```

else just write this...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity,this);
    mDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mDialog.show();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this on my Async Task.this is works like charm.

```
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityAddTicket.this);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.processing);
            dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
            dialog.show();
        };
```